# Which variety of Linux is best suited to work with R, SAS, SQL, Matlab?

Tags: software

Which variety of Linux is best suited to work with R, SAS, SQL, Matlab?
Is it Scientific Linux?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with commercial software like SAS or Matlab, use the distribution supported by the vendor.

For free software like R and databases it doesn't really matter. Use what you are familiar with or you can get support from friends and colleagues.